# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have a problem in several plugins

> image_picker: ^0.6.2+3 , location: ^2.3.5 ,...

I do **flutter clean** and nothing changed

Android device :**SM-N900**

Android Version:**5.0**

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
  }
}
```

**GeneratedPluginRegistrant**

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.deviceinfo.DeviceInfoPlugin());
      io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"));
      com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
      flutter.plugins.screen.screen.ScreenPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("flutter.plugins.screen.screen.ScreenPlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
      com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));
      altercode.xyz.uniqueidentifier.UniqueIdentifierPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("altercode.xyz.uniqueidentifier.UniqueIdentifierPlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin());
  }
}
```

**flutter doctor**

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    6.1.7601], locale en-US)
 Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.
3)
 Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

**One of My Exceptions is :**

> E/flutter ( 8362): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method serviceEnabled on channel lyokone/location)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): 
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #1      Location.serviceEnabled (package:location/location.dart:74:16)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #2      _SettingState._wifiStatus (package:flutter_example/Setting.dart:231:49)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #4      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #18     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #22     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
>   E/flutter ( 8362): #24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)

And my code :

```
var _locationService = new Location();

bool serviceStatus = await _locationService.serviceEnabled();
```

Comment: Your flutter doctor suggests that flutter is not properly configured on neither of the IDEs. Can you find those plugins under Project structure -> External Libraries -> Flutter Plugins. If not, please do flutter packages get

Comment: @Vamsi
yes ,i can find all plugins under  External Libraries 
i think it's not about Flutter version because i do create a new project and i test one of those  Libraries  and everything was OK, maybe its plugin dependence or IDK

Comment: I agree with @Vamsi. 
With this instances, first thing you can do is `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get`. Same as what happened in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/18). To further understand your issue, could you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a restart after adding the plugin? Running the app using `hot reload` may have yet to include the plugin that you've recently added on your build.